# Workbook Function

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a function, which requires the name of workbook, visible property and activate method as arguments. It is giving me "Object doesn't support this property of method error" on the isVisible line. How to fix this error? Thanks

```
Public Function wbOpen(wbTarget As String, isVisible As Boolean, doActivate As Boolean)
    Dim wb As Workbook  
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbTarget, , False)
    If isVisible = True Then wb.Visible = True
    If doActivate = True Then wb.Activate
End Function
```

Comment: There's no `Workbook.Visible` property... what do you want to make visible?

Comment: @BigBen Aah I just noticed and realized. It should be activewindow, but then how to use activewindow as argument. Thanks

Comment: Add a `Window` argument? Not sure what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen It's supposed to be ActiveWindow.Visible = True, got it

Comment: Wouldn't the opened workbook already be visible and active? Also the `ActiveWindow` *happens to* belong to `wb` here (most of the time anyway... might not always be the case though)... why not work with the `wb.Windows` collection and leave global state alone? By assigning `wb` you ignore the side-effects `Workbooks.Open` has on the `ActiveWorkbook` global state, and that's a very good thing. Consider `wb.Windows(1).Visible = isVisible`, and making `isVisible` and `doActive` optional parameters (e.g. `Optional ByVal isVisible As Boolean = True`)